# JavaScript , AJAX quick loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I have some ajax code:

```
      $(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    $("#button1").click(
    function()
    {
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update.php",
      });

    });
  });
```

In my html code I have 200 buttons. How can i loop buttons i this ajax code? I'm newbie of ajax and js.

I know I can copy and paste and change number of buttons but I think it's not optimalize code.

Thank's for help.

Comment: Why not use class selector?

Comment: you want set one click handler to all buttons, or what?

Comment: sounds like he wants all the buttons to trigger ajax call when clicked.  He should be using a class selector or something else....not an id.

Comment: It was that simple ;)) Thanks! Now I must paste my class selector x200 times:) Lets go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.php",
        });
    });
});


<button class="button" id="button1">button 1</button>
...
<button class="button" id="button200">button 200</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply some common class to the buttons to select all of them:

```
$(document).ready(
  function()
  {
     $(".myButtonClass").click(
    function()
    {
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update.php",
      });
    });
  });
```